# Views-based search analytics

Tags: views, search

I have a search: search terms field setup in a view in drupal 7. It's exposed to users so they can search nodes.

I know my users are using the search but google analytics isn't capturing that information.

I also looked at reports > top search phrases and it shows nothing...even though I believe views uses the basic search module.

My question is: is there a way to see statistics on what terms users are using to search with this view?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a possible answer. [Use Google Analytics module](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) and [make sure to track internal search](http://www.webwash.net/articles/how-track-site-search-queries-drupal). Then [setup your Google Analytics account like so](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264).